# trouble with some syntax of C++

Tags: c++

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
 public:
    A(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}
    void show() { cout << "i = " << i << endl;}
 private:
    int i;
};

class B {
 public:
    B(int xx) : x(xx) {}
    operator A() const { return A(x); }
 private:
    int x;
};

void g(A a)
{  a.show(); }

int main() {
  B b(10);
  g(b);
  g(20);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

In the above code can anyone explain what does the line

```
A(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}
```

mean and how the output of the program

```
i = 10
i = 20
```

Comment: Assuming it's the colon part you're confused about, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: ...and if it's `int ii = 0`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument

Comment: Time for a C++ tutorial/book [[suggested link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/)]

Comment: .. or: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: It's good example of bad variable names, which is probably the actual reason for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
A(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}
```

is class **A**'s constructor, and constructor has a value `ii`, and initializing `i` to `ii`.

**Output**

```
B b(10);
g(b);
g(20);
```

in this code, `g(20)` is pass temporary instance of class **B**.

because, the class **B**'s constructor is not `explicit` so `int` to `B` is OK.

Comment: Sorry sir, did not understand why g(20) is not an error ??

Comment: You need to understand c++ constructor. B'c constructor's parameter is int. So you pass int, than compiler can find B's Constructor. And automacally call B's constructor.

Comment: But A's Constructor also has int as the parameter ??

Comment: Oops. My mistake. But also class A's constructor has int. so if you pasa int, compiler will call A's conatructor.

Comment: Just one more question what does the line 

operator A() const { return A(x); }

mean ??

and why can g function accept and object of class B ??

Comment: operator mean Implicitlly converting B to A. So, when you pasa B class to g function, B's converting functions has called. So you can use B instance. PS. I'm not sir i just 14 years old programmer: )

Comment: Is this answer helpful? Than accept this answer please!

Answer (score 0):

This is declaring the constructor to `class A`

```
A(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}
```

This part declares that the constructor can take a single `int` parameter, that has a default value of `0`.

```
A(int ii = 0)
```

This part is initializing the member variable `i` with the value from the parameter `ii`.

```
i(ii)
```

Answer (score 0):

`A(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}`

is the constructor of class A and it takes an argument `ii`, which in the initializer list, is assigned to `i`. Then the body of it does nothing.

Equivalently you have:

```
A(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {
 // do nothing
}
```

Equivalently -in terms of result- you have:

```
A(int ii = 0) {
  i = ii;
}
```